# Android Studio - java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user

Tags: android, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I have to create an Android Studio application that relies on a SQL Server database. To establish the connection with the database, I have written the following code:

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.10.151:1433/databaseName=db_test;integratedSecurity=true;", "admin0", "admin0");
```

Of course the ip/database name and credentials that I've provided are not the ones I'm actually using.

I am however getting the following error: java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'admin0'

Having done some previous research before asking this question, I can assure you that I've already verified the following:

- The username and password used for my connection are correct
- The property "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode" is enabled in the security tab
- The property "Allow remote connections to this server" is enabled
- The TCP/IP property in the SQL Configuration Manager is enabled
- The firewall is disabled
- The SQL server port (1433) is enabled
- I am able to log on to SQL server using the user admin0, however that is not the case when using Android Studio
- The user admin0 has all the grants and privileges required

So, is there something else that I missed that could be the source of this issue?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for a related message that includes the specific cause of the login failed.

Comment: The logs don't seem to be triggered by my attempt to log in.